# How do I open a new instance of an application by default in GNOME?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome

I have a terminal open and want to launch another one. I hit the Windows key, type 'terminal' and hit `Enter`...and I'm warped to my first terminal.

I can hit `Control+Enter` to launch a new terminal. This is unnatural to me. Can I change the key bindings so that `Enter` will launch a new instance and `Control+Enter` will warp to the existing one?

Edit: I'm interested in all applications, not just a terminal.

Comment: did you figure it out ?

Comment: Vihaan, I installed MATE.

Comment: I ll stick to the control + enter :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Also answered here: [How to open new window instead of already open window in gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/579568/how-to-open-new-window-instead-of-already-open-window-in-gnome)

You can configure this globally with a tweak extension.

You can press <kbd>super</kbd> , write `tweak` , open tweak tools.

Then go to "extensions" and enable "launch new instance"

Example:

[image: Click HERE to see an example]

Comment: As the extension is not always installed by default, you can download it here https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/600/launch-new-instance/

Answer (score 3):

you can open new instance by pressing CNTRL + ENTER

Comment: Technically not an answer, but useful. As it is only a few programs where I want a new instance most of the time  - basically term - I can relearn this and stop fighting the goon^^^gnome squad

Answer (score 0):

- Goto System->Preferences->Keyboard Shortcuts
- Under Desktop category, choose Run a Terminal
- Now press the key you want to set as shortcut (I pressed Ctrl +T)
- Click close
- Now Ctrl + T is the Ubuntu Terminal Shortcut

Keep posting if this was not what you wanted...

Comment: Okay, that works for one application. What about the 147 others?

Comment: @dhasenan But you mentioned just abt terminal and not the rest 147 i guess ?

Comment: Uhm... Ctrl+T is standard tab key, don't you use tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Your pinned programs are 1, 2, 3, ... etc

**WinKEY** + **Shift** + **1** opens a new instance of your first program.

Holding down **WinKEY** + **Shift** should show you the program index over them; just in case you're confused which number to press.

For opening any program you will need a keystroke launcher. I only use one on windows (Launchy) and don't have need for one on ubuntu; so you'll have to google it. :)

Comment: This is exactly what I need but it doesn't work for me.