# How to open new window instead of already open window in gnome

Tags: gnome

When I have e.g. Firefox open and I press the Super key, type 'firefox' my existing window is shown. Can I change this to open a new window, instead of the already opened?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can start a new instance of a program just clicking on its launcher icon with your mouse middle button (usually it is a wheel that can also be clicked).

If you prefer the use of keyboard only, instead of pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to launch a new instance of an application.

Few programs do **not** support more than one instance running at the same time. For example Firefox will tell you there is an instance already running if you try to launch a second one. But it works for most of programs.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. However, the newer versions of the Firefox does not tell you and it opens the new instance.

Answer (score 8):

Repeated answer here: [How do I open a new instance of an application by default in GNOME?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125243/how-do-i-open-a-new-instance-of-an-application-by-default-in-gnome/770312#770312)

You can configure this globally with a tweak extension.

You can press <kbd>super</kbd> , write `tweak` , open tweak tools.

Then go to "extensions" and enable "launch new instance"

Example:

[image: Click HERE to see an example]