# Customize Super + N Behavior

Tags: shortcut-keys, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-dash

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with GNOME. When I hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, the first program in my left favorites bar, aka Ubuntu Dock (in my case, Firefox) starts up. If I hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> again, it switches to the existing Firefox instance. I would like it to start a new Firefox process instead.

I followed the instructions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125243/how-do-i-open-a-new-instance-of-an-application-by-default-in-gnome?noredirect=1), which works if I go into the launcher by hand, but it doesn't work for the keyboard shortcuts <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>, etc. Also, it seems that <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> is not listed as a keyboard shortcut in the settings, so I can't simply override the binding myself. How can I get a new process to start when I hit <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd>, for <kbd>Number</kbd> from 1 to 9?

Comment: Related: [Disable the default app key (super+num) functionality on Ubuntu 17.10 and later](https://askubuntu.com/q/968103/480481)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is controlled by the Ubuntu Dock gnome extension. It uses the same backend as the very popular Gnome Shell extension "Dash to Dock". There is no option to change the behaviour of the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd> keys. You can resort to a perhaps less perfect workaround.

**Workaround**: Disable that functionality of the dock. Then, use "Keyboard" - "Settings" to manually assign the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd> for launching applications according to how they are pinned on the launcher. For instance, assign the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> hotkey to launch Firefox.

To disable the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd> functionality of the Dock, open a terminal and issue following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys false
```

If you change your mind, you can restore the default behaviour with the command:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock hot-keys
```

In practice, this will work very well for your pinned applications. However, the hotkeys will not automatically be updated if you change the order of your favourites. Also, you cannot have corresponding <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Number</kbd> keys for icons that are not pinned as favourites, because these icons change all the time.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. In practice, I only use these shortcuts for ~3 applications, so assigning them by hand works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## Ubuntu 19.04 or Newer

I'm just posting a secondary answer in case someone finds this question later. The solution suggested by vanadium is sufficient on Ubuntu 18.04. If you're running 19.04 or 20.04, *in addition to his answer*, you also have to change

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock app-hotkey-1 '[]'
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.keybindings switch-to-application-1 '[]'
```

and do so for each keybinding you want to override (i.e. by changing the `1` to be the requisite digit). See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968103/disable-the-default-app-key-supernum-functionality-on-ubuntu-17-10-and-later) for more details.